# Parent Object for Custom Class of variable Type

Tags: excel, vba

I'm programming quite a complex thing in VBA I think and even though I did a lot of research I couldn't come up with a solution to my problem so far. And unfortunately I'm no expert :)

I have two classes, e.g. `clsBuilding` and `clsFactory`, which both have an instance of `clsHeatDemand`. Now I'm trying to implement a `parent`-Property to access some values from the base classes I need for the calculation, based on [this](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2007/12/28/terminating-dependent-classes/#comment-29661) idea.

```
Friend Property Get Parent() As clsBuilding
    Set Parent = ObjFromPtr(parentPtr)
End Property
Friend Property Set Parent(obj As clsBuilding)
    parentPtr = ObjPtr(obj)
End Property
```

My problem now is that the `parent` can be of two different types even though they have the same parameters I need. So what I'm trying to ask is if there is a way to hand over the instances simply as `obj As Object` and still access its properties?

I also tried this with Interfaces but I would be happy if there is another easier solution.

Comment: Make the two different types implement a common interface, and then use that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem because I still need to know the object type  beforehand .. I think I will try the interface-solution than

Comment: Why is that? If you're using them in exactly the same way with 2 different implementation, that's pretty much the definition of what an interface is *for*. You can also hold a weak reference to an interface. VBA's `Object` *is* an interface.

Comment: Guess you're right. Avoiding an interface would have been less writing, that was the only reason

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can help you, have a look at it.

' Class which has different parent

```
Option Explicit

Private m_parent As Variant

Public Property Get Parent() As Variant
    Set Parent = m_parent
End Property

Public Property Set Parent(ByVal vNewValue As Variant)
    Set m_parent = vNewValue
End Property

Public Function Name()
    If TypeName(m_parent) = "ParentA" Then
        Name = m_parent.Name
    Else
        Err.Raise 123, "Parent doesn't have Name"
    End If
End Function

Public Function Height()
    If TypeName(m_parent) = "ParentB" Then
        Height = m_parent.Height
    Else
        Err.Raise 456, "Parent doesn't have Height"
    End If
End Function
```

' ParentA

```
Public Name As String

Public Age As Integer
```

' ParentB

```
Public Height As Double

Public Weight As Double
```

' Test

```
Sub test()
    Dim c As Class
    Set c = New Class

    Dim pa As ParentA
    Set pa = New ParentA
    pa.Age = 5
    pa.Name = "Parent A"

    Dim pb As ParentB
    Set pb = New ParentB
    pb.Height = 15.5
    pb.Weight = 50.5

    Set c.Parent = pa
    Debug.Print c.Name


    Set c.Parent = pb
    Debug.Print c.Height
    Debug.Print c.Name
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is a good idea even though I'm not yet sure how to use it! Cheers

Comment: I was thinking you have two absolutely unrelated parent classes, where an interface is not possible to create, but when I was writing the answer, I was in a hurry and maybe I misunderstood your problem.